# Getting locale format for Windows

Tags: windows, delphi, datetime

how can I get correct locale's format for Windows in Delphi ?

I trying to do next

```
LCID := 2048;    
FormatSettings := TFormatSettings.Create(LCID);
```

but this doesn't work fine if set shortdate format as example **'07-13\2012'**.
and variable will be equal

**`FormatSettings = 'MM/dd\yyyy' ?????`**

Comment: And what would the value of `LCID` be?

Comment: You are trying to use a standard formatting routine on a non-standard date format. The example you give, uses two different date-separators. There's no way to define this as a proper date format. For the rest, use the code in Gerald's answer to get your system's default formatsettings.

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to use this non-standard format? Wouldn't it be easier to stick to a standard format, or do you like pain?!  ;-)

Comment: Use custom format for support all cases if user change your locale

Comment: I don't understand that at all.

Comment: Are you saying you're using a custom format so that your software is locale independent?

Comment: Yes, software is locale dependent

Answer (score 1):

You could use this?

```
var
   formatSettings : TFormatSettings;

 begin
  // Furnish the locale format settings record
   GetLocaleFormatSettings(LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, formatSettings);

  // And use it in the thread safe form of CurrToStrF
   ShowMessage('1234.56 formats as = '+
               CurrToStrF(1234.56, ffCurrency, 4, formatSettings));
 end;
```

http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=GetLocaleFormatSettings

Comment: This function is same as above I write

procedure GetLocaleFormatSettings(Locale: TLocaleID; var AFormatSettings: TFormatSettings);
begin
  AFormatSettings := TFormatSettings.Create(Locale);
end;

Answer (score 1):

in fact you should consider date as:

```
TShortDateFormatParts = (sdfpPrefix, sdfpDatePart1, sdfpSplitter1, sdfpDatePart2, sdfpSplitter2, sdfpDatePart3, sdfpSuffix);
```

in your code you should:

1. Find and get everything before leading "d", or "M" or "Y" (prefix).
2. Find and get text before first splitter.
3. Find and get end of first splitter.
4. Find and get text before second splitter.
5. Find and get end of second splitter.
6. Find and get everything before final text (suffix).
7. Get what we have now is final part

after:

Get position of DAY, MONTH and YEAR in current format string

Answer (score 0):

The first lines of TFormatSettings.Create(Locale) are:

```
  if not IsValidLocale(Locale, LCID_INSTALLED) then
    Locale := GetThreadLocale;
```

When I pass LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT (2048) as my locale, IsValidLocale returns false and GetThreadLocale returns 4105 (Canadian-English).  You may want to investigate this further.  Are you getting the locale that you expecting?

Comment: @Young Please don't shout at people that are trying to help. The reason you have not yet got an an answer that satisfies you is because your question is so poor. I realise English is not your first language, but you must try harder to explain what it is that you are doing. I recommend that you edit the question and spend some significant time and effort in making it clear what your are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

The correct format of the locale for countries

```
var
  formatSettings : TFormatSettings;
begin
  GetLocaleFormatSettings(LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, formatSettings);
  ShowMessage('LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT = ' + DateTimeToStr(now, formatSettings));

  GetLocaleFormatSettings(MAKELANGID(LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US), formatSettings);
  ShowMessage('LANG_ENGLISH = ' + DateTimeToStr(now, formatSettings));

  GetLocaleFormatSettings(MAKELANGID(LANG_RUSSIAN, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), formatSettings);
  ShowMessage('LANG_RUSSIAN = ' + DateTimeToStr(now, formatSettings));
end;
```